# Fetch column value based on dynamic input

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a `dataframe`, where in I have 1 column, which contains names of column satisfying certain conditions for each row.

It's like if columns of dataframe are Index, `Col1, Col2, Col3`, `Col_Name`. Where Col_Name has either `Col1 or Col2 or Col3` for each row.

Now in a new column say Col_New, I want output for each row such as if 5th row `Col_Name` mentions `Col_1`, then value of `Col_1` in 5th row.

I am sorry I cannot post the code I am working on, hence gave this hypothetical example.

Obliged for any help, thanks.

Comment: I can think of applying a for loop, however that will drastically slow down my code, hence wish to know a better method.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, but can't you apply to Col_New the same condition that you apply to pick the string in Col_Name?

Comment: @micric I guess if I go into too much detail without posting the code, that will make my question confusing. However I had used np.argsort to arrive at an array of column names in descending order based on value in each row. Now w.r.t. one column, I need corresponding value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you could use:

```
df['col_new'] = df.reset_index().apply(lambda x: df.at[x['index'], x['col_name']], axis=1)
```

#### Example:

```
cols = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3), columns=cols)
df['Col_Name'] = np.random.choice(cols, 10)
print(df)

       Col1      Col2      Col3 Col_Name
0  0.833988  0.939254  0.256450     Col2
1  0.675909  0.609494  0.641944     Col3
2  0.877474  0.971299  0.218273     Col3
3  0.201189  0.265742  0.800580     Col2
4  0.397945  0.135153  0.941313     Col2
5  0.666252  0.697983  0.164768     Col2
6  0.863377  0.839421  0.601316     Col2
7  0.138975  0.731359  0.379258     Col3
8  0.412148  0.541033  0.197861     Col2
9  0.980040  0.506752  0.823274     Col3    

df['Col_New'] = df.reset_index().apply(lambda x: df.at[x['index'], x['Col_Name']], axis=1)
```

[out]

```
       Col1      Col2      Col3 Col_Name   Col_New
0  0.833988  0.939254  0.256450     Col2  0.939254
1  0.675909  0.609494  0.641944     Col3  0.641944
2  0.877474  0.971299  0.218273     Col3  0.218273
3  0.201189  0.265742  0.800580     Col2  0.265742
4  0.397945  0.135153  0.941313     Col2  0.135153
5  0.666252  0.697983  0.164768     Col2  0.697983
6  0.863377  0.839421  0.601316     Col2  0.839421
7  0.138975  0.731359  0.379258     Col3  0.379258
8  0.412148  0.541033  0.197861     Col2  0.541033
9  0.980040  0.506752  0.823274     Col3  0.823274
```

#### Example 2 (based on integer col references)

```
cols = [1, 2, 3]
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3), columns=cols)
df[13] = np.random.choice(cols, 10)

print(df)

        1         2         3   13
0  0.548814  0.715189  0.602763   3
1  0.544883  0.423655  0.645894   3
2  0.437587  0.891773  0.963663   1
3  0.383442  0.791725  0.528895   3
4  0.568045  0.925597  0.071036   1
5  0.087129  0.020218  0.832620   1
6  0.778157  0.870012  0.978618   1
7  0.799159  0.461479  0.780529   2
8  0.118274  0.639921  0.143353   2
9  0.944669  0.521848  0.414662   3
```

Instead use:

```
df['Col_New'] = df.reset_index().apply(lambda x: df.at[int(x['index']), int(x[13])], axis=1)

          1         2         3  13   Col_New
0  0.548814  0.715189  0.602763   3  0.602763
1  0.544883  0.423655  0.645894   3  0.645894
2  0.437587  0.891773  0.963663   1  0.437587
3  0.383442  0.791725  0.528895   3  0.528895
4  0.568045  0.925597  0.071036   1  0.568045
5  0.087129  0.020218  0.832620   1  0.087129
6  0.778157  0.870012  0.978618   1  0.778157
7  0.799159  0.461479  0.780529   2  0.461479
8  0.118274  0.639921  0.143353   2  0.639921
9  0.944669  0.521848  0.414662   3  0.414662
```

Comment: Getting an error KeyError('Col_Name', occurred at index 0')

Comment: I guess it's some problem with my column naming, actually the column Col_Name in my hypothetical example is actually 4 which is numeric value rather string, hence this error may be occurring. Will figure out first to convert it to string, then apply lambda you mentioned. Will update the results here.

Comment: can you try again please, I updated my answer with your naming conversions

Comment: Chris can you rename Col_Name as any integer say 13 and then check if it works

Comment: I added an example based on integer column references that works for me... are you able to check?

Comment: Trying it out, got an error saying str object has no attribute astype

Data type handling is always a nightmare for me :(

Comment: I updated it to remove `.astype`. use `int()` instead

Comment: I understand that Chris, will try to figure something out. Thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: Solved it Chris. A little immature tweak, renamed the integer column as a string and then used your lambda.... Thank again, you are a lifesaver

Answer (score 0):

Using the example DataFrame from Chris A.

You could do it like this:

```
cols = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3), columns=cols)
df['Col_Name'] = np.random.choice(cols, 10)

print(df)
df['Col_New'] = [df.loc[df.index[i],j]for i,j in enumerate(df.Col_Name)]

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

In pandas is for this function [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html), also it seems need same types of values in columns and looking  column, so is possible convert both to strings:

```
np.random.seed(123)
cols = [1, 2, 3]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 3)), columns=cols).rename(columns=str)
df['Col_Name'] = np.random.choice(cols, 5)

df['Col_New'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['Col_Name'].astype(str))
print(df)

   1  2  3  Col_Name  Col_New
0  2  2  6         3        6
1  1  3  9         2        3
2  6  1  0         1        6
3  1  9  0         1        1
4  0  9  3         1        0
```